# Add event listener to array of elemnts

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have an Array of elements & another Array of objects in the same arrangement index & I need to add on click event for each element to display a property of each object.

For example :

```
myDivArray = [ div0, div1, div2];
myObjectArray = [object0, object1, object2];

myDivArray[1].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = my object[1].name
});
```

Of course name is a property in that object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `forEach` to iterate

```
myDivArray.forEach( function( el, index ){
  el.addEventListener( "click", function(){
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = myObjectArray[ index ].name; 
  })
})
```

Comment: what to be added for element parameter ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Which element parameter?

Comment: what is (el) ??
myDivArray.forEach( function( el, index ){
  el.addEventListener( "click", function(){
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = myObjectArray[ index ].name; 
  })
})

Comment: El is the item of the myDivArray of the in the iteration. Read more about forEach.

Comment: typescript forEach function already deprecated in typescript  that's why it isn't work with me

thank's for your help :)

Comment: You can use map or any other way to iterate the array.